# SPARK CONTEXT with JSON Data

Tags: sql, json, dataframe, apache-spark

Where am I falling short?

```
jsonStrings= '{"Zipcode":704,"ZipCodeType":"STANDARD","City":"PARC PARQUE","State":"PR"}'

jsonRDD = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([jsonStrings])

df = spark.read.option('multiline', "true").json(jsonRDD)

print(df.show())

ERROR----------------

raise converted from None pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: {"Zipcode":704,%22ZipCodeType%22:%22STANDARD%22,%22City%22:%22PARC%20PARQUE%22,%22State%22:%22PR%22%7D
```

Answer (score 0):

json() here `spark.read.option('multiline', "true").json(jsonRDD)` expects path to data, not RDD. Documentation is [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.json)

If you want to create df from json string, you can do it like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Row

df = spark.createDataFrame(
   spark.sparkContext.parallelize([Row(json=jsonStrings)])
)
```

Comment: Thnx Artem for the suggestion. I did try the approach